# blazor why this property being full with private variable or simple change / throws exception or not

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, blazor

lets say that i have

```
public  class IntStrDict
{
  private List<KeyValuePair<int?, string>> _values = new();
  public  List<KeyValuePair<int?, string>> Values
  {
     get => _values;
     set => _values = value;
  }

   public string GetVal(int? Key)
   {
     if (Key == null ) return string.Empty;
     return Values.Where(x => x.Key == Key).Single().Value;
       
   }
}
```

and in component

```
@inject DictService _ds;
IntStrDict? _dict1 ;
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{ 
  _dict1= await _ds.GetIntStrDict();
 }
```

and some table that in RowTemplate have

```
  <MudTd DataLabel="dict1">
        @_dict1?.GetVal(@context.dict1)
        </MudTd>
```

**and this works fine**

but if i change

```
private List<KeyValuePair<int?, string>> _values = new();
  public  List<KeyValuePair<int?, string>> Values
  {
     get => _values;
     set => _values = value;
  }
```

to

```
 public  List<KeyValuePair<int?, string>> Values= new();
```

then i get runtime errors on everyline that use this `GetVal` because offcourse sequence contains no elements (`.single()`)

**why when property is full then it waits till this Values are loaded and on short property it does not wait and except?**

thanks and regards

Comment: `public  List<KeyValuePair<int?, string>> Values= new();` is  a field...
`public  List<KeyValuePair<int?, string>> Values { get; set;} = new();` is a property...

Comment: ok i see thanks but why this change so much ??????